# Как включить ActiveX в WebBrowser C#?

Tags: c#, webbrowser, activex

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты! Пишу автосёрфер для одного сайта, он использует ActiveX. Как включить ActiveX в WebBrowser C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже спаривался сам, ответ нашел тут - http://rsdn.ru/article/files/dotnet/WebBrowser.xml